# How to remove duplications in DolphinDB?

Tags: dolphindb

When using DolphinDB to save data multiple times, is there a mechanism to ensure that the data is not duplicated, or is it necessary to manually compare each time?

Answer (score 0):

The TSDB engine support to remove the duplicated records. Please specify the engine parameter to TSDB while creating a database, and specify the keepDuplicates parameter of the "createPartitionedTable" function to select the Deduplication strategy.